# FFMPEG Does not work on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Site ,the user can upload a video and When Done It finish uploading I show him an image extracted from the Video,
To do this I used the FFMPEG exe to get  a frame.
Everthing works well in the developement machine , when I use the test environement it does not work!!
I've given the read/write and execute permissions to following folders:
1. videos(folder that store uploaded video files)
2. thumbnails (folder that store the thumbnails of videos, captured by ffmpeg)
3.ffmpeg.exe file at root and given read/write  execute permissions to that file also. 
but it does not work.

```
 var _converter = new ImageConvertor(@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FFmpegExec"].ToString());
            _converter.WorkingPath = Server.MapPath("~/VideoSamples");
            OutputPackage oo = _converter.ConvertToFLV(videoFilepath);
            FileStream outStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/VideoSamples"), id.ToString() + ".flv"));
            oo.VideoStream.WriteTo(outStream);
```

This Code Works on developement env but not in test env !!!
Any Ideas Please

Comment: Is your test env medium trust? Does your app pool have permission to run external processes? In any case you should probably have your app queue requests for a non-IIS-hosted service to do the processing for you.

Comment: So I have to check into my App pool in IIS  to find if I can run external process ? If not I have to activate this?

Comment: Actually I guess the permissions on disk probably take care of that and it's more likely to be medium trust denying you permissions inside .NET.

Comment: When I check the task manager I see the FFmpeg started and completed , so the external app has started

Comment: No error , juste the covnertor does not convert ( to flv)